# In React how to check input radio checked or not only if the variable is defined ?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

Works fine if already has selected answer in the sate like this

```
this.state = {
  answers: [
    {
      questionID: "1",
      answerValues: "2"
    }
  ]
};
```

In default empty state is  `this.state = { answers: [] };` the console says **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'answerValues' of undefined** at `checked={option.id == checked.answerValues}`. Of course it will not work because the object is empty.

```
<input
  name={name}
  id={`${name}-${option.id}`}
  data-question-id={questionID}
  type="radio"
  onChange={onChange}
  value={option.id}
  checked={option.id == checked.answerValues}
  /> {option.value}
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/wyymx2jvrw

Is there any option in JSX to check input checked only when `answers: []` is not empty

Comment: Your missing a lot of vital code. Where does checked variable come from?

Comment: @JoelHarkes by default is there is not checked variable available. It is adding to state when the user selected from radio button. You can see in the link https://codesandbox.io/s/mm4qrv4o6j it works fine if the user already has selected answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With reference to the code sandbox:
Error has nothing to do with the react. It is plain old js.
You are trying to access a property on undefined & that is not valid.

`{option.id == checked.answerValues}` here `checked` is passed in as a property to the `InputRadio` component. If you don't pass a value, it will be undefined by default.

A quick fix will be setting a defaultValue for the property. An empty object will be a right candidate.

See it working with a default value in the fork of your sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/n58j54pr84

relevant portion of the code

```
const InputRadio = ({
  name,
  label,
  questionID,
  onChange,
  value,
  options,
  checked = {}  // <--- set a default value
}) => {
```

Comment: yah, Default Parameters in ES6 which can solve such issues  thanks a lot for remaining buddy  I can only give single up vote sorry for that and thanks a lot for the quick solution